# python debug straightforward datetime object

Tags: python, datetime

I cannot understand why this is failing, can someone please explain:

```
import datetime

def test(timestamp):
    xt = datetime(2013, 4,4)
    dt = datetime.strptime(timestamp, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
    print (xt,dt)

test('04/04/2013 08:37:20')
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 12, in 
  File "", line 5, in test
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

It seems to work ok with `from datetime import datetime` instead. I can't understand what the difference is.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because in the `datetime` module, there is a `datetime()` function, but you didn't call it ( you instead tried to call the module, that's why you got a `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`).

```
import datetime
def test(timestamp):
    xt = datetime(2013, 4,4) # Problem is this line.
    dt = datetime.strptime(timestamp, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
    print (xt,dt)

test('04/04/2013 08:37:20')
```

To fix the line, change it to:

```
xt = datetime.datetime(2013,4,4)
```

The reason `from datetime import datetime` worked was because you imported the specific function, and so you wouldn't need to do `datetime.datetime()`.

Comment: The line below must also be changed to `dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')` in order to run for me.

Answer (score 1):

`datetime` is both a module AND a class in that module. In your example you need `datetime.datetime`.

Answer (score 1):

The

```
xt = datetime(2013, 4,4)
```

should be

```
xt = datetime.datetime(2013, 4,4)
```

Here, `datetime` is the name of the module. The full name of the class is `datetime.datetime`.

Answer (score 1):

Here `datetime` can refer to the module or the class within the module so you have to disambiguate

```
import datetime

def test(timestamp):
    xt = datetime.datetime(2013, 4,4)
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
    print (xt,dt)

test('04/04/2013 08:37:20')
```

gives the following output:

`(datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 4, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 4, 8, 37, 20))`

Answer (score 1):

`datetime` is the datetime *module*, `datetime.datetime` is the datetime *type*:

```python
import datetime

def test(timestamp):
    xt = datetime.datetime(2013, 4,4)
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
    print (xt,dt)
```